# Field api - taking responsibility over a field display

Tags: 7, entities

I am writing a Drupal module that deals with the taxonomy terms, which are (as I understand) fields, taxonomy vocabulary , which are as I understand entities. My module should take over the taxonomy term field and vocabulary entity for mirror language display, meaning that once my user is in X language, he will see the X language value of the term/vocabulary name/description.

Looking at the i18n_taxonomy module code I can see that it implements many fields related functions (`i18n_taxonomy_field_attach_view_alter()`, `i18n_taxonomy_field_formatter_view()`, `i18n_taxonomy_field_formatter_info()`, etc). My questions are:

- Once I need to to take over a display of a field, how can I do it?
- What functions should my module implement for displaying the fields on menus, widgets, plain view, etc?
- Same question, only for the vocabulary: is there any difference?
- I have spent my time googling this subject, but I have not really found a good reference. Can anyone refer me to one?

Comment: Both terms and vocabularies are entities. "Taxonomy reference" is a field, which you can attach to other entities to assign terms to them.

Answer (score 1):

Fields are displayed through formatters (you can have multiple ones, and then you chose which one you want when adding the field to a content type, or any bundle of an entity).
So, hook_field_formatter_info() and hook_field_formatter_view(). 
Open the core image module: modules/image/image.field.inc in your Drupal install, and use that as an example.

You can use hook_field_formatter_info_alter() to add formatters to existing field types (not declared by your mpdule).